# Set global_frame and robot_base_frame parameters for costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS object

Tags: ros, occupancygrid

I am trying to use a `costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS` object to read the occupacy grid being published on the `/map` topic. How do I modify the values of the `global_frame` and the `robot_base_frame` parameters for the costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS object? I tried to go through the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d#Coordinate_frame_and_tf_parameters). But, I didn't really get it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple *consumer* of Costmap information is not expected to use this class. The expectation is that you subscribe to the costmap topic, and receive `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` messages. The `data` field of this message contains a 2D grid of cost for each cell. For this message, the 2D grid has been flattened to 1D, so you use the `height` and `width` metadata to recreate the 2D coordinates.

Typically the `costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS` class is used internally by `move_base` to buffer data, merge updates and do other maintenance stuff. Consumers of costmap data don't perform these operations. Inside move_base, the frame_ids are obtained from the ros parameter server - a simple consumer doesn't modify these values.